# Right to left TListView

Tags: delphi

I am programming a tlistview so that it displays its columns from right to left (so as to properly display Hebrew text). I am using the following code in the form's create method, where 'lv' is the listview

```
 SetWindowLong (lv.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
                GetWindowLong(lv.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE)  or
                WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT);

 lv.invalidate;
```

Whilst this code makes the lines in the listview display correctly, the header line displays from left to right! The columns don't match up and the heading for each column is wrong.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the header line to display right to left?

I am using Delphi 7, not that this should make much difference.

TIA,
No'am

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the full code to set the header and the lines:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  LVM_FIRST = $1000;      // ListView messages
  LVM_GETHEADER = LVM_FIRST + 31;
var
  header: thandle;
begin
  header:= SendMessage (lv.Handle, LVM_GETHEADER, 0, 0);
  SetWindowLong (header, GWL_EXSTYLE,
                 GetWindowLong (header, GWL_EXSTYLE)  or
                 WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT);

  SetWindowLong (lv.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
                 GetWindowLong (lv.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE)  or
                 WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or WS_EX_NOINHERITLAYOUT);
  lv.invalidate;   // get the list view to display right to left
end;
```

Comment: After executing the above code, right click (popup menu) would not work! Any idea?

Comment: It also mirrors icons horizontally, (Delphi 2010+Win10). +1 BTW.

Comment: Later I found it even mirrors check boxes, [more deails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53968824/2093077).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this sample'll be useful for you :

```
var
  aCol: TListColumn;
  tmp: TListView;
  i: integer;
begin
  tmp := TListView.Create(Self);
  LV.Columns.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for i := LV.Columns.Count-1 downto 0 do
    begin
      aCol := tmp.Columns.Add;
      aCol.Width := LV.Columns[i].Width;
      aCol.Caption := LV.Columns[i].Caption;
    end;
    LV.Columns := tmp.Columns;
  finally
    LV.Columns.EndUpdate;
    tmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. I've just found the answer - see below.